# How to store data while scraping in case of script failure?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm doing some web scraping (actually geocoding using a web service) and writing the results to a file:

```
for i, row in enumerate(data):
  data[0] = url
  output = {}
  try: 
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
      results = r.json()
      if results:
        output['Lat'] = results['wgs84_lat']
        output['Lng'] = results['wgs84_lon']
        writer.writerow(output)
  except:
    pass
```

My problem is that if something goes wrong half-way through and I have to stop the process, I end up with a half-written file.

Then I have two choices: I can either restart from scratch (tedious with a million rows to geocode), or I can add boilerplate code to check whether the row already exists in the output file, and skip it if so.

I feel there must be a more convenient way to check whether the row has already been obtained. What's the neatest, most Pythonic way to do this? Perhaps `pickle` (which I've never used?

Comment: Is it perhaps an option to dump all records in a database and just select those where latitude/longitude is null?

Comment: Yes... but I feel sure there must be a simpler way even than that. I just need to store any rows that have already been collected.

Comment: you could just store `i` in a separate file and check if `i > stored_value` in your loop. I take it that data here is an array of 1 million rows?

Comment: Yes it is - that might be the simplest solution I guess.